# Replace Every Other Digit

Tags: regex

### This is a quiz exercise

Replace every other character if it's a \d with `*` (only those in even positions: 2, 4, 6, etc). Example: `a1b2cde3~g45hi6` should become `a*b*cde*~g4*hi6`

I tried the code

```
(?<=.)(\d)
```

Substitution

```
*
```

### Result

> Test 3/10: Remember to replace only all digits in even positions of the string.

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QAHt6E/1)

Comment: E.g. `\G((?:.\D)*.)\d` -> `$1*`

Comment: You can post on the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\G((?:.\D)*.)\d
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ta2VWd/1). Make sure the `.` matches any char by using the corresponding option for your regex engine if the input string may contain line breaks.

**Details**

- `\G` - start of a string or end of the previous match
- `((?:.\D)*.)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:.\D)*` - a non-capturing group matching 0 or more repetitions of any char and any non-digit char
  - `.`  - any  1 char
- `\d` - a digit.

A JS regex (ES6 compliant) for this might look like

```
/((?:.\D)*.)\d/gy
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ta2VWd/2/). The `y` flag together with `g` flag help achieve the same affect as using `\G` operator in the former regex.

A short demo:

```js
var s = "a1b2cde3~g45hi6";
var rx = /((?:.\D)*.)\d/gy;
console.log(s.replace(rx, "$1*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

@WiktorStribiżew already gave a great answer. If you're using one of the few regex engines that supports variable-width lookbehind patterns, however, you can also use:

```
(?<=^(?:..)*.)\d
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QAHt6E/3